# PropertyGrid display Textbox inline, not as a dropdown

Tags: c#, user-interface, propertygrid

[This question (How to create a PropertyGrid editor that limits a string to n characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014021/how-to-create-a-propertygrid-editor-that-limits-a-string-to-n-characters) almost does exactly what I need, but instead of using a drop-down, I'd like the edit to happen in the grid itself.

[image]

`UITypeEditorEditStyle` doesn't seem to be of much help because setting it to None eliminates the textbox control entirely.

Or, is there an easier way to get access to the TextBox that the control is using to hook into events there?

Ultimately, I'm looking for a text-entry widget that limits the length of the input that's 1. done inline, and 2. without having to wait until the user stops typing to give them an error or truncate the input.

Comment: PropertyGrid is the Ford Model T of UI design: "the customer can pick any color, as long as it is black".  At least you get 3 choices, textbox is the default, combobox or dialog for a custom editor.  Input validation needs to occur in the type converter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a TypeConverter that would restrict the text once it's been entered. That would work only the textbox looses the focus. Let's suppose I have this class I want to edit using the property grid:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(MyTypeConverter))]
    public string MyText { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a type converter code that does this:

```
public class MyTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public const int MaxLength = 10;

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return Truncate(value as string, MaxLength);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        return Truncate(value as string, MaxLength);
    }

    private static string Truncate(string value, int maxLength)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        return value.Length <= maxLength ? value : value.Substring(0, maxLength);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you can hack the grid, like I demonstrate here. It's not a UITypeEditor because the underlying textbox is shared for all items. The following approach is based on selection events. Again, this is another class I want to edit:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Editor(typeof(NoneEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public string MyText { get; set; }

    public string MyOtherText { get; set; }
}
```

Note the MyText property is decorated with a "marker" editor that just does nothing:

```
public class NoneEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.None;
    }
}
```

I can just hook the grid, like this:

```
propertyGrid1.SelectedGridItemChanged += OnPropertyGridSelectedGridItemChanged;

    public static void OnPropertyGridSelectedGridItemChanged(object sender, SelectedGridItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyGrid pg = (PropertyGrid)sender;
        GridItem item = e.NewSelection;

        // yes, a grid item is also an IServiceProvider
        IServiceProvider sp = (IServiceProvider)item;

        // get the property grid view control
        IWindowsFormsEditorService svc = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)sp.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));

        // WARNING: hack time! this uses private members, so use at your own risks...
        TextBox edit = (TextBox)svc.GetType().GetProperty("Edit", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(svc, null);

        // is this our funky stuff?
        if (item.PropertyDescriptor.GetEditor(typeof(UITypeEditor)) is NoneEditor)
        {
            edit.MaxLength = 10;
            edit.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }
        else // don't forget to reset the edit box here
        {
            edit.MaxLength = int.MaxValue;
            edit.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wound up using a variation of your hook into `SelectedGridItemChanged`, and it worked really well.  I'd been down the trail of subclassing the `PropertyGrid`... and eventually wandered into something like this anyway.  Thanks.